# Big Oh notation for this specific cost function

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, stack, dynamic-resizing

Question: what is the big oh notation for the cost of a stack (that implements an array) that doubles the size of its array if it needs more space. it dynamically resizes larger, but not smaller.

ex:

```
N = [size]
1 = [x]
2 = [x,x]
3 = [x,x,x,x]
4 = [x,x,x,x]
5 = [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
6 = [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
7 = [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
8 = [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
9 = [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
10 =[x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
```

I got it as:

```
T(N) = Summation from i = 0, to log_2(N) of (2^i)
```

which is equivalent to `(2^(log_2(n))) + 1`

which I interpret as `O(2^N)`, because `lim as n -> infinity of log_2(n) = infinity`.

So in essence ... what is Big Oh for this: `(2^(log_2(n))) + 1`

Comment: **Not sure** but u can try asking this question at the website for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user3471847 Please consider accepting an answer by clicking on the check mark against an answer below. Also see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135493/informing-new-users-of-how-to-accept-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a hard time figuring out your analysis of the code. Rather, you can convince yourself that the running time will indeed be O(N) by the following analysis:

For storing N elements, you will resize the array after the 2nd, 4th, 8th, 16th, 32nd, 64th, .....2^x element, where 2^x = N.

Thus, x = log_2 N

At each resize operation a cost equal to the size of the array is incurred. Thus the total resizing overhead can be expressed as:

```
cost = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 ......2^x
     = (2^x-1)/(2-1)    
     = 2^x - 1 
     = 2^(log_2 N) - 1 
     = N^(log_2 2)-1 
     = N-1 
     = O(N)
```